# iOS - Two Tableviews in one ViewController, each with different data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to place to TableViews inside of one ViewController. My UISegmentControl in the navigation bar switches between the two of them. E.g. if one is showing, the other is hidden. That said, I want to display one type of cell and data for self.tableView, and a different cell with different data for self.friendsView.

The first one self.tableView populates seamlessly, however self.friendsView doesn't seem to load its custom cell (though the data is coming through the console). Am I structuring the below correctly? If not, how can I correct it?

**.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myFriendData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *friendData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *friendsView;
```

**.m**

```
      - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"sidebarCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.sidetableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"sidebarCell"];

    //to register next cell
    nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyFriendTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.friendsView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"MyFriendTableViewCell"];



            }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView == self.sidetableView) {


 /*
    static NSString *NetworkTableIdentifier = @"MyFriendTableViewCell";

    MyFriendTableViewCell *cell = (MyFriendTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NetworkTableIdentifier];
    if (tableView == self.tableView)

    {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyFriendTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
         */

    MyFriendTableViewCell *cell = (MyFriendTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyFriendTableViewCell"];



        NSDictionary *friendsName = [self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell friendName] setText:[friendsName objectForKey:@"title"]];

        NSDictionary *friendsBio = [self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell friendBio] setText:[friendsBio objectForKey:@"field_friendbio"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"]];


        NSString *profilePath = [[self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"field_picture"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];


        [cell.friendPic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

        NSLog(@"This is profilePath %@",profilePath);

    return cell;

}



    if (tableView == self.friendsView)

    {

      /*  static NSString *NetworkTableIdentifier = @"sidebarCell";

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

        sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NetworkTableIdentifier];
        //  if (tableView == self.friendsView) */

        sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sidebarCell"];


        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"sidebarCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDictionary *userName = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell username] setText:[userName objectForKey:@"node_title"]];


        NSDictionary *userBio = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell userDescription] setText:[userBio objectForKey:@"body"]];

        NSString *profilePath = [[self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"friendphoto"];

        [cell.usermini sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

        return cell;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What about other `UITableViewDataSource` protocol methods? And you shouldn't have class name begin with non capital character. `sidebarCell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a return statement for each of the tableview.

```
    if (tableView == self.sidetableView)

    {
       ....
       return cell;
    }

    if (tableView == self.friendsView)

    {
       ....
        return cell;
    }
```

Another mistake I see is you are assigning two different references to the cell.
For example:

```
sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NetworkTableIdentifier];
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"sidebarCell" owner:self options:nil];
 cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

Don't do this.If you are loadin the cell from xib, frist register it in the viewDidLoad.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"sidebarCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.sidetableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"sidebarCell"];

    //to register next cell
    nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyFriendTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self. friendsView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier: @"MyFriendTableViewCell"];

    }
```

and in the cellForRow method, call it as:

FYI: class names always start with capital letter

```
 SidebarCell *cell = (SidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sidebarCell"];
```

Comment: Placing UINib *nib inside viewDidLoad throws me an "Undeclared value NetworkTableIdentifier" error?

Comment: I updated my answer, youshould use "MyFriendTableViewCell" for friends cell, and use "sidebarCell" for sidebarcell!

Comment: Can I do this even if each table is using a different cell? *nib is only one cell?

Comment: if you are using 2 different cell, you need to register it twice, using different cell identifier.

Comment: Ok, so [[self tableView]] in the second declaration be the name of my other tableView? e.g. friendsView? and on your last line of code, NetworkTableIdentifier should now be @"sidebarCell" ? Correct?

Comment: yes. cell 1 is for tablevie1, then register it for tableview1.

Comment: See above updated code. When I do this, for some reason XCode throws me the error "Pointer cannot be cast to type 'CGFloat (aka 'double')" on my -GCFloat line right after return cell. Gah! Why! Lol

Comment: you need to have another return statemtn outside the two if-conditons to satisfy the compiler. Just declare a dummy cell. UITableViewcell *cell; and then do return cell below the last if condition;

Comment: No idea why, but self.friendsView still isn't loading its custom cell (while self.tableView works fine).

Comment: in your viewDidLoad, you used [self tableView] . You should use self.tableView for first cell, and self.friendsView for second

Comment: I updated my answer. Also pls use a different name sideTableView instead just tableView to give it more readabaility!

Comment: Ok, did the above. Lol now I get this crash error: failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Comment: pls update ur question with what youhave, and I can see what is wrong.

Comment: do you have the re-use identifers entered correctly in the cell xib's ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding xib as a cell you could directly use a custom view for your table view.Any ways See if it works.

// Do something like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *myCell;

  if (tableView == self.sidetableView) {


  /*
   static NSString *NetworkTableIdentifier = @"MyFriendTableViewCell";

   MyFriendTableViewCell *cell = (MyFriendTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NetworkTableIdentifier];
   if (tableView == self.tableView)

  {

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyFriendTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
     */

MyFriendTableViewCell *cell = (MyFriendTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyFriendTableViewCell"];



    NSDictionary *friendsName = [self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell friendName] setText:[friendsName objectForKey:@"title"]];

    NSDictionary *friendsBio = [self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell friendBio] setText:[friendsBio objectForKey:@"field_friendbio"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"]];


    NSString *profilePath = [[self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"field_picture"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];


    [cell.friendPic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

    NSLog(@"This is profilePath %@",profilePath);

 myCell = cell

}



else if (tableView == self.friendsView)

{

  /*  static NSString *NetworkTableIdentifier = @"sidebarCell";

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NetworkTableIdentifier];
    //  if (tableView == self.friendsView) */

    sidebarCell *cell = (sidebarCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sidebarCell"];


    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"sidebarCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDictionary *userName = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell username] setText:[userName objectForKey:@"node_title"]];


    NSDictionary *userBio = [self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell userDescription] setText:[userBio objectForKey:@"body"]];

    NSString *profilePath = [[self.friendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"friendphoto"];

    [cell.usermini sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePath]];

    myCell = cell;
}


return myCell;
}
```